# Caught a throwable exception during processing Closed Resultset: next

Tags: exception, jdbc, resultset

So I did try checking for answers before I could ask this question again, I'm getting a closed ResultSet exception for my code below.
The same code worked on development environment when tested for a small set of records. But on QA environment the exception is encountered for 200-300 records being fetched by the query as well. 
My question is, if there is no close statement or close connection code why is the closed resultset exception thrown at the While loop in the code below?

```
public void extractRecordsAndUpdateData() throws Throwable {
    ConnectionManager mgr =null;

    /*
    * Some authentication code here for user authentication to allow access in the application
    */

    Connection c = null;
    try {
        mgr = mServiceLocator.getConnectionManager();
    }
    catch (Exception newex) {
        newex.printStackTrace();
        customLogWriter.logEntry("Got a Exception during authentication " + newex.getMessage());
    }

    PreparedStatement pSql = null;
    ResultSet myResultSet = null;

    try {
        c = mgr.getConnection(mgr.getSiteName());
        pSql = c.prepareStatement(extractSQL); // extractSQL is a simple select statement fetching records from DB to be processed in the while loop below.
        myResultSet = pSql.executeQuery();

    }catch(SQLException ex){customLogWriter.logEntry("Error " + ex.getMessage());}

    List<List> outerList=new ArrayList<List>();
    while (myResultSet.next())  // Exception encountered on this line of code
    { 
        /*Do some processing*/
    }

    customLogWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Poorly structured exception handling. The `ResultSet.next()` loop should be inside the `try` block. You should only have one `try` and one `catch (SQLException ...)` here.

Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block.

Comment: Agree, The code is being updated, but would like to understand what could be the actual issue here? Is it that the resultSet is empty and gives a closed resultset exception or any other issue?

Comment: I'm wondering whether you've posted the real code. If `myResultSet` was an instance member rather than a local variable, your present code structure would allow you to call `next()` after an exception in the prior `try` block, which would mean you were reusing a previous `ResultSet` that had already been closed.